# Run setInterval several times, then pause for several seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I need my code to run x amount of times and then pause for 30 seconds or so before resuming. Any ideas?

```
myslidefunction();
var tid = setInterval(myslidefunction, 1000);

function myslidefunction() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        //do stuff  
    }, 400); 
};
```

Comment: why you don't use setInterval(myslidefunction, 1400)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can keep a *run-count*, and use `normal_duration + 30000` as the `setTimeout` delay for the *X+ 1st* time.

```
var runCount = 0, runsBeforeDelay = 20;
function myslidefunction(){

    // .. stuff

    runCount++;
    var delay = 0;
    if(runCount > runsBeforeDelay) {
        runCount = 0;
        delay = 30000;
    }
    setTimeout(myslidefunction, 400 + delay);
};

// start it off
setTimeout(myslidefunction, 1000);
```

Comment: Don't you want `setInterval()`?  `setTimeout()` will only run once.

Comment: @DerekHenderson He has called setTimeOut from the function itself. So it is a kind of recursive call.

Comment: Great answer! Many don't realize that UI programming in JavaScript sometimes involves recursive algorithms. :)  One suggestion, to avoid myslidefunction getting eval'd by the JS engine, place it in an anonymous function in the setTimeout's first argument, like so: `setTimeout(function() { myslidefunction(); }, 400 + delay);`.  Platforms that have a Content Security Policy enabled, like Chrome's packaged apps platform, will throw errors or warnings. Plus, eval can theoretically be unsafe. :)  Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;

var mySlideFunction = function(){

    /* your "do stuff" code here */

    counter++;
    if(counter>=10){
        counter = 0;
        setTimeout(mySlideFunction, 30000);
    }else{
        setTimeout(mySlideFunction, 1000);
    }
}

mySlideFunction();
```

Comment: This way you also have an option to stop the iteration at any given point, instead of trying to time it with a clearInterval();